# Tangent plane of a surface at points with given gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surfaces

So I'm stuck on the next problem:

I need to find the tangent plane of the surface $$u=\ln\left( x+\frac{1}{y} \right)$$
at all the points where the gradient is equal to $$\nabla u=\hat i-\frac{16}{9}\hat j$$

Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: What are you missing ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust as i wrote... i need to find the tangent plane, i dont remember how to do it..... thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to find the point(s) where you have to give the tangent plane.

For the gradient you have:
$$\nabla u = \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x},\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right) = \left( \frac{1}{x+1/y},\frac{-1/y^2}{x+1/y} \right)$$
And you're looking for the points $(x,y)$ where this is equal to $\left( 1,-\tfrac{16}{9}\right)$, so:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \frac{1}{\color{blue}{x+1/y}} & =&  1 \\[8pt]
\displaystyle \frac{-1/y^2}{\color{blue}{x+1/y}} &=& \displaystyle -\frac{16}{9}
\end{array}\right.$$
From the first equation it is obvious that $\color{blue}{x+1/y=1}$ , so the second equations yields:
$$-\frac{1}{y^2}=-\frac{16}{9} \Leftrightarrow y^2 = \frac{9}{16}$$
This gives $y = \pm \tfrac{3}{4}$ and that leads to the points:
$$\left( -\frac{1}{3},\frac{3}{4}\right) \, , \, \left( \frac{7}{3},-\frac{3}{4}\right)$$
Now use  the formula for the [tangent plane](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentPlane.html) at the surface $u=f(x,y)$ in $(x_0,y_0)$:
$$u =f(x_0,y_0) + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x-x_0)+ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(y-y_0) $$
Do this for both points with the desired gradient.

Comment: wow thank you very mcuh!!!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: so i get 2 answers?:

$$u =x-\frac{16}{9}y+\frac{5}{3} $$
$$u =x-\frac{16}{9}y-\frac{11}{3} $$

Comment: Yes, those are correct!